# No candle sticks are shown using Bokeh Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, bokeh

I am trying to run the following code for displaying the candle stick pattern for my dataframe.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

from math import pi

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1000, title = "MSFT Candlestick")
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p.segment(df.index, high, df.index, low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.index[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

#output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

show(p)  # open a browser
```

I am not getting anything in the output. Kindly, let me know what I have missed so I improve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using almost exactly the code from the [Bokeh examples](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html). If you run the example it will open up without problems.
Unfortunately in the code you pasted *df*, *high* and *low* are not defined and I can't help you very much without those.